# Facebook Graph API não retorna todos os usuários

Tags: facebook

Estou usando o Facebook Graph API para retornar os usuários que curtiram um determinado Post. Tanto na página do Facebook, quanto o sumário da consulta me retornam um número de usuários, só que no array tenho usuários a menos. O post abaixo, por exemplo, teve 27 curtidas, mas no array só retornam 26 usuários. Por que isso acontece? É alguma configuração de privacidade do usuário?

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/119932011417602_818812144862915/likes?fields=name&limit=30&summary=true